# VB.net real time synchronizing clock

Tags: vb.net, clock

I have here a working code but the output is in 24hour format:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
Timer1.Enabled = True 
End Sub 

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
Label1.Text = Now.TimeOfDay.ToString() 
End Sub
```

I used a timer but my output looks like this:

17:00:30.123456

I want my output to be like this in 12hour format:

5:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it here is my 12 hour format code:

```
Label1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
```